# Make YouTube API Request from chrome extension (CORB)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am working on a chrome extension which is intended to find related YouTube videos on a music review site. Up until recently, it worked without issues. However, chrome recently enabled [CORB](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers) by default and now my requests to the YouTube API get blocked with the following error:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with
>   MIME type application/json. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details

Specifically, the API I'm trying to access is "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search".

I am making an XMLHttpRequest to send the request.

```
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
request.send();
```

Is the problem with my request?

Comment: The error message has a link to the page that contains various solutions, including [the one for extensions](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) with examples and info.

Comment: @wOxxOm dang. I visited the page, but didn't notice the chrome extension mention. Thanks.